# dateByAddingTimeInterval not giving desired result in IOS app development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I am having the following objective C code:

```
 NSString *dateStr = @"2012-09-21 05:00:00";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateNew = [formatter2 dateFromString:dateStr];  
//NSLog(@"date new %@" , [dateNew description]);

NSDate *dateConverted = [dateNew dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
//NSLog(@"date converted=%@",dateConverted);

NSString *dateConvertedStr = [formatter2 stringFromDate:dateConverted];
NSLog(@"date conv str=%@",dateConvertedStr);
```

Here i am trying to first convert a date string into date object(dateNew). Then an interval is added to it to get new dateConverted. Lastly, this date object is converted to string again and printed.
But i am not getting desired results.
For eg: for given date string, if interval is 45000.00, then it is basically 12.5 hrs. So, my dateConvertedStr should give '2012-09-21 17:30:00'. But it is not giving desired results.
Can anybody suggest. Am i missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the format string you supply. In your example (given that interval is `45000.00f`) it returns `date conv str=2012-09-21 5:30:00` because you use 12h based format.

Try this instead (note the capital `H`):

```
[formatter2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

And now your `dateConvertedStr` is `2012-09-21 17:30:00` as expected.